# How do I disable form onsubmit if there is an error?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, form-submit

I have a form that collects user data and inserts into a database. Before submission, the data is validated and upon submission the window closes. I'm using try/catch for error handling so when there is an error I do not want the window to close.

This is what the form line looks like:

```
<form target="_self"  method="post" id = "questionnaire" class="validate" onsubmit="submit();window.close()">
```

Essentially what I'm trying to do is if there is an error onsubmit=""

Thanks

Comment: <form onSubmit = "return false; submit();"> This way, inside your submit() method you can trigger if it is valid.

Comment: @Rottingham — That way, the submit function will never be called.

Comment: Make `submit()` return false if there's any error, then use `onsubmit = "return submit();"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle the `submit` event of your form, and cancel the submission.

Here's a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TtnH4/4/)

#### Unobtrustive Javascript without jQuery

```
//Get the form element.
var form = document.getElementById('questionnaire');

//Declare your event handler
var onMyFormSubmit = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event; //Get the event if it's not passed in.

    if (!valid) { //Do your validation here.
        e.returnValue = false;
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
};

//Attach an event handler to the submit event.
if (form.addEventListener) {
    form.addEventListener('submit', onMyFormSubmit, false);
} else {
    form.attachEvent('onsubmit', onMyFormSubmit);
}
```

Comment: This is impressive, but why this way? Is it more browser-compatible?

Comment: @redolent A) It doesn't require jQuery. B) It supports older versions of IE which don't use `addEventListener`. C) It doesn't require you to muddy up the HTML with calls to Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submit()
{
    // do error checking
    if ( /*passes*/ )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
</script>

<form target="_self"  method="post" id="questionnaire" class="validate" onsubmit="return submit();">
```

Comment: According to this post, `submit` is a reserved word: [Onsubmit function called submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35395433/onsubmit-function-called-submit).