# Onsubmit function called submit

Tags: javascript, html, onsubmit

I am wondering why `onsubmit` global scoped function cannot be called `submit`. I didnt find any reason.

This doesnt work:

```
<form onsubmit="return submit();">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<script>
    function submit() { alert('Hey!'); return false; }
</script>
```

This does work:

```html
<form onsubmit="return test();">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<script>
    function test() { alert('Hey!'); return false; }
</script>
```

Comment: Because handler is executed within a form context (`this` = form), and form already has a `submit()` prototype method which takes preference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp) is a list of Javascript's reserved words.
As you can see, `submit` is one of them !

Comment: Oh my... I am a fool... Thanks! :D

Comment: I really don't know, as it is the only website where I could a find a reference to `submit`

Comment: It is not a reserved word. Specifically, you can write `onsubmit="return window.submit()"` and it works.